# How to write a comparison result correctly in simple sentence

Tags: word-choice, comparison, comparative-constructions

I have two methods. The first method needs `30` steps to be done. The second method needs only `10-15` steps. I would like to compare the steps that each method needed to be done.

Here is my sentence:

1. 1- The number of iterations is reduced to (almost) the half of the
   iterations that the EM-method needed to converge when not using the second method.

or

2. The number of iteration of the second method was (almost) the half of the iteration that was required for the first method.

Which one is correct?

Another sentence:

***All models show poor fit, where the first model is the poorest one.***

Is this a correct comparison in English?

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructions are unnecessarily complex, which makes them hard to follow.

Note that **steps** and iterations are not the same thing. But if you prefer iterations, you might say:

> The first method requires more than twice as many iterations as the second.

or

> The second method requires less than half as many iterations as the first.

Your sentence regarding the **models** is also awkward.

I would suggest:

> All models fit poorly (or badly); the first model fits worst.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iteration